# Merge Sort - Segmentation Error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I've been programming in Python for more than a year now, and I just moved back to C++, to learn a few basic algorithms. I started with merge sort, but it gives me a segmentation errror. Help would be greatly appreciated. I think I debugged where it happens, but I'm unable to understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void* merge(int array1[], int array2[], int low, int mid, int high){
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = low,j = mid, k = low; i < mid, j < high; k++){
        if (array1[i] < array1[j]){
            array2[k] = array1[i];
            i++;
            }
        else{
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (i == mid){
        for (; j < high; j++, k++){
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            }
    }
else{
    for (; i < mid; i++, k++){
        array2[k] = array1[i];
    }
}
void* merge_sort(int array1[], int copy[], int low, int high){
    int mid;
    int range = high - low;
    if (range == 1)
        copy[low] = array1[low];
    else{
        mid = low + range/2;
        merge_sort(array1, copy, low, mid);
        // Segmentation error seems to be here.
        merge_sort(array1, copy, mid, high);
     }
     merge(array1, copy, low, mid, high);
}

int main()
{
    int n, temp;
    cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int numarray[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> numarray[i];
    }
    int dumarray[n];  // Used for filling elements from merge sort
    merge_sort(numarray, dumarray, 0, n);
    cout << "Merge Sort" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << dumarray[i] << endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge_sort(int [], int [], int, int);

void merge(int array1[], int array2[], int low, int mid, int high){
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = low,j = mid, k = low; i < mid, j < high; k++){
        if (array1[i] < array1[j]){
            array2[k] = array1[i];
            i++;
            }
        else{
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (i == mid){
        for (; j < high; j++, k++){
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            }
    }
    else{
        for (; i < mid; i++, k++){
            array2[k] = array1[i];
            }
    }
}

void merge_sort(int array1[], int copy[], int low, int high){
    int mid;
    int range = high - low;
    mid = low + range/2;
    if (range == 1)
        copy[low] = array1[low];
    else{
        mid = low + range/2;
        merge_sort(array1, copy, low, mid);
        merge_sort(array1, copy, mid, high);
    merge(array1, copy, low, mid, high);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n, temp;
cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter?" << endl;
cin >> n;
int numarray[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> numarray[i];
}
    int dumarray[n];
    merge_sort(numarray, dumarray ,0, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << dumarray[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't even compile

Comment: @aaronman : I'm using g++ , and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: It doesn't compile in g++. Missing braces among other other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation for mid value seems to be wrong. Try calculating mid as

`mid = low + (high-low)/2`

Edit: Move `merge(array1, copy, low, mid, high);`inside the else bracket.

```
else
{
    mid = low + range/2;
    merge_sort(array1, copy, low, mid);
    merge_sort(array1, copy, mid, high);
    merge(array1, copy, low, mid, high);
}
```

The `merge` function also has a lot of bugs. The condition check in the initial for loop
`i < mid, j < high` is separated by a comma which means it is only checking for `j < high` and discarding condition check for i.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is wrong. But still it gives me a segmentation error.

Comment: @Manoj Why have you kept the return type for `merge` and `merge_sort` as `void *`. It doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: You need to continue merging until i becomes equal to mid and j becomes equal to high. Therefore, set the condition as `i<mid || j<high` and check for all the cases where both `i < mid` and `j < high`, `i == mid` but `j < high`, and `i < mid but j == high`

Comment: Finally managed to fix it, I was comparing array2 when I was supposed to be comparing array1. Thanks :)